# Next-auth middleware authorization for 2 tipes of user by role

Tags: authentication, next.js, middleware, roles, next-auth

I have a middleware in "NEXT 13" to prevent access in routes like '/profile' if the user is not authenticated. I want to implement "admin" access to '/dashboard' route but i cant add this const to the matcher parameter inside config.

This is my middleware.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'

const adminRoutes = ['/dashboard']

export default withAuth(function middleware(req) {
    if (
        adminRoutes.includes(req.nextUrl.pathname) &&
        req.nextauth.token?.role !== 'admin'
    ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url))
    }
})
const privateRoutes = ['/profile']
const routes = privateRoutes.concat(adminRoutes)
export const config = {
    matcher: routes
}
```

It works if i write like this:

```
export const config = {
    matcher: ['/profile']
}
```

But when I add a const like "routes", "privateRoutes" or "adminRoutes" the application breaks.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you